# The security module on Chromebook is not working. How to fix this?

Tags: chromebook

When I press the tab it shows;

> HWID: SNOW BASIN AA-J 0135
> recovery_reason: 0x05 TPM error in read-only firmware

I have tried to insert a recovery USB flash drive following the steps provided in Chromebook recovery but as soon as I insert the USB flash drive it displays a message saying that the security module on this device is not working.

Can someone lend a help here?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The only fix that worked was to clear the processor.

1. Remove the recovery USB flash drive that you have inserted.
2. Turn off by pressing the on/off key for 3 to 5 seconds (have to do this because no GUI).
3. Wait for a few seconds then press start button and wait a few seconds for it to restart.
4. Recovery screen will come up.  Leave it for at least 30 seconds - don't do anything else.
5. Shut down again. You will have to do this restart/shutdown procedure several times.

Some say up to 20 times so a lot of patience required.  I had to do about 10 restarts before it worked.

If this doesn't work for you, it may be a hardware fault.